# spark 1.3.0, python, avro files, driver-class-path set in spark-defaults.conf, but not seen by slaves

Tags: python, hadoop, apache-spark, avro

I am using spark 1.3.0, with python. I have an application that reads an avro file using the following commands :

```
conf = None

rddAvro = sc.newAPIHadoopFile(
    fileAvro,
    "org.apache.avro.mapreduce.AvroKeyInputFormat",
    "org.apache.avro.mapred.AvroKey",    
    "org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable",
    KeyConverter="org.apache.spark.examples.pythonconverters.AvroWrapperToJavaConverter",
    conf=conf)
```

In my `conf/spark-defaults.conf` I have the following line:

```
spark.driver.extraClassPath /pathto/spark-1.3.0/lib/spark-examples-1.3.0-hadoop2.4.0.jar
```

I have setup a cluster of three machines (two masters and a slave):

- If I run `spark-submit --master local` on the master, it works
- If I run `spark-submit --master local` on either slaves, it works
- If I run `sbin/start-all.sh` and then `spark-submit --master spark://cluster-data-master:7077` it fails with the following error :

  ```
  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
  org.apache.spark.examples.pythonconverters.AvroWrapperToJavaConverter
  ```

I can reproduce this error in local model by commenting the driver line in the `.conf` file. I tried `spark-submit` with appropriate `--driver-class-path` but it does not work neither !

**Update with solution**

Following a request here is what works for me :

- I use `spark-submit --driver-class-path path/to/appropriate.jar` when calling the script
- I have nothing related to jar files in the `spark-defaults.conf file`
- I forward the jar path to executors using
  `SparkConf().set(...).set("spark.executor.extraClassPath","path/to/appropriate.ja‌​r")` in the main python file.

I totally gave up on using the conf file for setting the path. I did not try the `--jars` argument yet as suggested by fanfabbb below, may be worth a shot.

Comment: I finally made it work, using the --driver-class-path argument rather than the .conf setup. I will update when I have more details !

Comment: for me, using PySpark in spark 1.3.1 the --jars argument is actually enough.

Comment: Yep, whatever option that forwards the class to _executors_ works.

Comment: I am having a hard time reading the avro file into pyspark.I get the error An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.newAPIHadoopRDD.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.avro.mapreduce.AvroKeyInputFormat. Could you please explain in detail the changes you made?

Comment: In my case I use a conjonction of two setups :  --driver-class-path path/to/appropriate.jar, nothing related to jar files in the .conf file, and I set in the context : SparkConf().set(...).set("spark.executor.extraClassPath","path/to/appropriate.jar"). I totally gave up on using the conf file for setting the path. I did not try the --jars argument yet as suggested by fanfabbb above, may be worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

try running it with the option --master yarn-cluster

Depending on the size of the data you may have allocate more memory per container by adding more numbers to the following config parameters:

## yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb

## yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb

spark-submit   --master yarn-client --num-executors 5  --driver-cores 8  --driver-memory 50G --executor-memory 44G code_to_run.py